# Display images from facebook in separate thumbnails

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing windows phone application. here I am taking some images from Facebook.All images coming in horizontal scrolling one after other

Problem: how to add some blank space between two images

This is my code so far:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate> 
        <StackPanel 
          Orientation="Horizontal"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" > 
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=picture}" Width="250" Height="250" /> 
        </StackPanel> 
    </DataTemplate> 
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >



                                 <Image Source="{Binding Path=picture}"  Width="250" Height="250" />


                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution set Margin Of Image control inside datatemplate of listbox.

```
<ListBox  Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
       <Image Source="{Binding FacebookImages}" Stretch = "Fill" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```