# How to retrieve Facebook image description

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing windows phone application. I am retrieving event images from Facebook.
Problem:
how to take detail information about the event like date place of image by clicking on that image

Comment: from facebook I am getting iamges. Now i want to write a code that on click onany image detail description of that event image like date venue should display

Comment: I meant: what code did you already write. Show some effort (i.e. code) first.

Comment: first i declare list<events> then used jobject and jtoken then switch case for event time event date and event place

Comment: Did you see my edit of [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701567/display-images-from-facebook-in-separate-thumbnails)? Please add some actual code to this question too. And consider reading [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are using listbox then

 private void YourList_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FaceBookClass fbc = YourEventList.SelectedItem as FaceBookClass ;
            String date=fbc.Date;
             String place=fbc.Place;
        }
```